# Click on JQuery menu widget programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I have a created a drop down menu on a tab. It contains some link and I have written the logic to be performed after each button click in the onClick event of the menu. The links in the does nothing and just fires the onClick of the menu widget and it take care of the rest.

```
var menuList = {
        onClick : function(e, menuItem) {
            //logic to per based on event clicked
        }
    };
    $('#menuTab').menu(menuList);

<span id="menuTab" >
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="alloptions">Options</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="l1">l1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="l2">l2</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="l3">l3</a></li>
        </ul>
</span>
```

It performs all the logic correctly when it is clicked manually, now i want to do some automation but I am not able to click the links programmatically, how can i go about it ?

I have tried `document.getElementById('l1').click()`. It would be better if you can suggest something just using click as all the other automation code is only using `.click`. Thanks.

Comment: I do not know which plugin you use for the menu, but if the `onClick` gets correctly attached to your elements, then `document.getElementById('l1').click()` should trigger the event. [here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qs9nujh/1/).

Comment: I am getting the element by `document.getElementById('l1')` but `.click` is not triggerng the onClick function declared

Comment: there is no click event registered at this element then. Three possibilities come to mind. **#1** The handler gets attached after you trigger the `click()` . **#2** The handler gets attached to another element e.g. the `li` parent of the `#l1` **#3** The handler does not get attached at all. You said you can trigger the handler manually, so 3 seems unlikely.

Comment: Read some documents online, my conclusion is that its the second case you mentioned, Its getting attached to the `li` parent. In that case how can i trigger the click ?

Comment: In jQuery `$('#l1).closest('li').click();`

Comment: Was not able to click using this way too. Did some hit and try and now `this.menuItems[1].$eLI.click()` way is working for me. Can you suggest some simpler way to do this

Comment: You could do sth like `conosle.log( this.menuItems[1].$eLI );` and check which element that is. Based on that info you could change the selector, but i dont know if that would be much simpler

Comment: Thanks will work this out and write it as answer